# Having the number of line having a specifc ID without group by SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a 'billing' table which represent all instances of billings from my subscribers. A subscriber can have multiple billings.

I have a simple SQL request which is :

```
SELECT count(billing_id),subscriber_id
FROM billing
   group by subscriber_id
```

As a result I have a list of all my subscribers with the number of billings they've made. 
I want to have a list of all the billings no grouped by subscribers, but I want the result of the previous request appearing in each lines.

Example:
Result of my previous request:

```
sub_id      nb_billings
  1             3
  2             2
```

What I want :

```
sub_id      nb_billings
  1             3
  1             3
  1             3
  2             2
  2             2
```

Thanks

Comment: Why? that's strange requirement ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this;

```
SELECT
    b.subscriber_id
    ,a.billing_count
FROM billing b
JOIN (SELECT subscriber_id, count(billing_id) billing_count FROM billing GROUP BY subscriber_id) a
    ON b.subscriber_id = a.subscriber_id
```

The subquery works out the count of billing_id by subscriber, this is then joined to all rows of your original table (using subscriber_id). This should give the result you're after.

Comment: I guess this is wrong. See here -> http://rextester.com/IUKAP28031 . The total count is in 5 and 6, far above the total number of rows in the table.

Comment: @SatwikNadkarny what makes you believe that this is wrong? It matches OP's request exactly (and has been accepted by the OP). From the question " I want to have a list of all the billings no grouped by subscribers" it doesn't mention grouping by the billing_id at all.

Comment: Because as you can see in the link, the result shows the count incorrectly. Why are all the counts shown as 5 for subscriber id 1 and 6 for subscriber id 2 ?

Comment: @SatwikNadkarny because that's what OP asked for. He's shown in his sample data that he has 3 rows for ID = 1 and 2 for ID = 2. He then wants to show 3 rows for ID = 1 that all say 3 and 2 rows for ID = 2 that all say 2.

Comment: Well that seems to be a case of "my bad" for me. The answer makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery to do that:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT count(t2.billing_id) FROM billing t2 WHERE t2.subscriber_id = t1.subscriber_id),
    t1.subscriber_id
FROM billing t1
```

Comment: am afraid about the performance of this query on large dataset

Comment: @Rahul U're right, then op can take the solution like **@Rich Benner**‘s.

Comment: Accepted the other answer as it was more optimised but used yours because it is clear and easy(the request is pretty complicated by itself so this solution is simple to set up)

Answer (score 1):

I guess this should suffice :

```
SELECT      s.subscriber_id,
            s.billing_id,
            s.TotalCount
FROM        (
                SELECT      subscriber_id,
                            billing_id,
                            COUNT(billing_id) AS TotalCount

                FROM        BILLING
                GROUP BY    subscriber_id,
                            billing_id
            ) s
GROUP BY    s.subscriber_id,
            s.TotalCount,
            s.billing_id

ORDER BY    s.subscriber_id
```

This should give you the result as follows :

```
subscriber_id   billing_id  TotalCount
1                   10a         2
1                   10b         2
1                   10c         1
2                   10a         1
2                   10b         1
2                   10c         3
2                   10d         1
```

You can see this here -> http://rextester.com/AVVS23801

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I don't think the OP wanted it to be grouped by billing_id as well as subscriber_id by the looks of it.

Answer (score -1):

```
select subscriber_id,count(billing_id)over(partition by subscriber_id)
from billing
```

will do just that.